# .htaccess importar outro arquivo com regra

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, importação, include

Galera, tenho o seguinte problema, tenho uma área administrativa onde pode ser cadastrado redirecionamentos de páginas, e esses redirecionamentos ficam salvos no banco, atualmente faço o redirecionamento via `PHP`, mas gostaria de passar a fazer esse redirecionamento via `htaccess`. Então estou fazendo o seguinte estou criando um arquivo chamado `.htaccess2` na raiz do meu site com essas regras que estão cadastradas no banco, sempre que realiza uma alteração ou insere um novo registro eu gero novamente esse arquivo. Agora minha dúvida é como faço para importar ou incluir esse arquivo dentro do meu `.htaccess`, algo nesse estilo:

```
Include .htaccess2
```

Alguém conhece alguma forma de realizar uma operação nesse estilo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode incluir regras, declarações, definições, ou diretivas de outros arquivos em um arquivo .htaccess. A diretiva *include* não pode ser usada dentro de um arquivo .htaccess. A função de um arquivo .htaccess é agir de forma semelhante a um bloco , mas ser auto-suficiente e não acessar coisas fora do próprio diretório. Desta forma, alguém que deseja fazer coisas mal-intencionadas não vai ser capaz de apontar solicitações ou incluir arquivos / conteúdo de outros diretórios *hackeando* o arquivo .htaccess.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640511/include-another-htaccess-file-from-htaccess)

Comment: Então eu teria de continuar fazendo o redirecionamento via php?

Comment: Isso, teria que fazer via php.